# net.tcp no longer works in server 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-server-2012

I cannot get server 2012 iis to host net.tcp.

In server 2008R2/VS2012 there is no issues

In server2012/VS2012 when hitting the wdsl I am first receiving "The protocol 'net.tcp' does not have an implementation of HostedTransportConfiguration type registered.", then if I hit refresh I get "An item with the same key has already been added."

The error from the TraceViewer if "service is unable to open its IChannelListener"

But I have set the Bindings on the default website( had to use the command line because it throws an exception if you edit net.tcp in the grid, this is a known issue)

I have set the bindings at the application level to http,net.tcp, created a new AppPool with network service identity, and used findPrivateKey to give it permissions.

I created a new virt of Server 2008R2/VS2012 and had no issues with the above steps.

*Edit Additional notes for server 2012

Add Roles and Features:

Verified the following are installed:

Web Sever - Application Development: All checked but CGI and ASP(classic)

.NET Framework 3.5 Features: All checked

Windows Process Activation Service: All checked

IIS: Default Web Site: bindings net.tcp 8081:*
IIS: Default Web Site->Advanced Settings->enabled protocols: http,net.tcp
IIS: Default Web Site\Service->Advanced Settings->enabled protocols: http,net.tcp

Is there anything special to do for Server2012?

Comment: Is the service enabled?

Comment: @ChaosPandion -It should be, is there an explicit setting I need to check?

Comment: What about the firewall? Does IIS automatically "punch a hole" in the firewall for your web service?

Comment: @fourpastmidnight I have turned the firewall off for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of searching, finally found it. I guess it another known issue with server2012 & IIS8

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803161

Answer (score 0):

Here some tips that you could try:

1-Open a Command Prompt (as administrator) and run:
netstat -ona

Check if your service is listening to your server port.

Example: your endpoint is net.tcp://localhost:8015/MyService. So running the command above, you will see an item:
TCP   127.0.0.1:8015 0.0.0.0 LISTENING

2-If your service is not listening, then create a Console app and self-host your service. 
Example:

```
using System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost;
public class Sample
{
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

public static void Main()
{
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("listening...");

        Console.Read();

        host.Close();
    }
}
```

3-Repeat the first step and check if your service is listening to the port.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but finally found another known issue with server2012